# How to set row order in a Datatable

Tags: rows, datatables, fixed

I am dynamically creating a table HTML and then applying jquery data plugin on my table. I have some specific rows that I want to always appear first in my table. Even I am writing my dynamic HTML first in the string for such rows but still at times while show/hide those rows at run time, they appear at the table end when shown back. Is there any way to do this? Hope I am clear in my question

As an example

[image]

Below is how I am initializing my data table

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollY": scrollY,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bStateSave": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

where **#myTable** is dynamic HTML table.
As shown in the example I want Row 1 and Row 2 to always appear first even if I show hide them.

Comment: How do you initialize the datatable?

Comment: $("#myTable").dataTable({my options }) where #myTable is a dynamically generated HTML table.

Comment: Hey, it is `({my options })`  that is interesting :) can you update your question with the initialization code?